# How to launch multiple processes on Debian: this code works on Alpine but not on Debian

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, debian, alpine-linux

[On Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/CTFS2TJK/how-do-i-run-multiple-processes-on-a-dyno) they suggest to use the below code to launch multiple processes on a container:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# set -x

trap '' SIGTERM

puma -C config/puma.rb &

sidekiq &

wait -n

kill -SIGTERM -$$

wait
```

Using alpine it works.

If I switch to debian (11) it does not anymore with these errors:

```
trap: SIGTERM: bad trap
```

and if I comment that:

```
wait: Illegal option -n
```

How can I translate this code to be compatible with Debian 11?

Comment: Use `/bin/bash` on Debian instead of `/bin/sh` (`/bin/sh` is a very minimal bourne shell on Debian and related distributions).

Comment: Specifically `/bin/sh` on Debian and derivatives is a symlink to `/bin/dash` ...

Comment: So what's your suggestion?

Comment: Can you launch two separate containers, one running the main Puma (Rails?) server, and a second running the Sidekiq worker?  The two containers could use the same image but override the command to run one component or the other.  This approach tends to be easier to manage and scale, especially if one of the processes might fail at runtime.